# Refresh Page Ajax Flask Web Application

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask

I'd like to make an ajax call when I press submit on my form it refreshes the page.
I'm having troubles because when I add a new comment it only updates the page when I refresh it manually, but if I do it, it posts another post on and on.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <form method="POST" action="/create_politician_comment/{{politician.idPolitician}}/{{g.user.uid}}">
        {{ form2.hidden_tag() }}
        <label for="comment">Comment:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="body" rows="5" id="comment" type="text"></textarea>
        <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" role="button"  onClick="document.location.reload(true)" type="submit" > {{ form2.submit }} </a>
    </form>
</div>
```

And here's my create_politician_comment function:

```
@politicians_blueprint.route("/create_politician_comment/<idPol>/<userId>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def create_politician_comment(idPol = 1, userId = 1):
  politician = Politic.query.filter_by(idPolitician=idPol).first()
  form2 = PostForm()
  form2.idPolitician = idPol
  form2.idUser = userId
  form2.timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()

  if request.method == "POST":
    users=db.session.query(User).all()
    politicianComments=db.session.query(PoliticianComment).filter_by(idPolitician=idPol).all()
    flash(form2.errors)
    flash(form2.validate())
    newComment = PoliticianComment(form2.body.data, form2.idPolitician, form2.idUser, form2.timestamp)
    db.session.add(newComment)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New comment was successfully posted', 'info')
    return render_template("politician.html", datetime=datetime, users=users, politicianComments=politicianComments, role_query=PoliticianRole.query, dom_query=Domain.query,org_query=Organization.query, idPolitician=idPol, politician=politician,form2=form2)

  elif request.method == "GET":
    return form2
```

Does anyone know why the onclick reload isnt working? Do I need to make this using an ajax call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you press your submit button there is no Ajax involved here. Pressing will result in a *POST* request to your *comment* route. There you handle the data and return *HTML* which will be displayed in your browser. I guess what you want is a simple redirect to your *politician* route. So instead of

```
return render_template("politician.html", datetime=datetime, users=users, politicianComments=politicianComments, role_query=PoliticianRole.query, dom_query=Domain.query,org_query=Organization.query, idPolitician=idPol, politician=politician,form2=form2)
```

your should use

```
return redirect(url_for('politician'))
```

This way your end up on your main page again.